# trying to make a filter with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

its strange.. but this code works only once. If i try to re-select - i get an empty table. It seems that re-select is not working properly.

Controller:

```html
  function filter(Request $request){
     if ($request->id == 'all'){
      $goods = Good::with('Shop')->get();
      $shops = Shop::all ();
      return redirect()->back();
     }else{
      $goods = Good::where('shop_id', $request->id)->get();
      $shops = Shop::all ();
      return view('filter')->with(['goods' => $goods, 'shops' => $shops]);
     }
    }
```

blade file:

```html
<form action = "{{ route('filter') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
     <select name="id">
      @foreach ($shops as $shop)
     <option value="{{$shop->id}}" @if (old('shop_id') == $shop->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{$shop->name}} {{$shop->adress}}</option>
      @endforeach;
     <option value="all">All</option>
     </select>
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pasirinkti">
    </form>
```

I feel that i need to somehow delete old values from request before re-submitting selection. Or something else :) thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest you dd(request()->all()) and check your request and differences. Can you let us know about the request()->all() for first and second calls of function

Comment: Show us your routes. You're sending a post request to a controller method which does redirection as well as display a view. That's bad code practise. Post your routes and explain which view/route should be displayed after filtering.

Comment: Route::get('/toBuy', 'GoodController@toBuy'); - the original route for landing page. Route::post('/filter', 'GoodController@filter')->name('filter') - route for the filter. Also toBuy function -   function toBuy(){
     $goods = Good::with('Shop')->get();
     $shops = Shop::all ();
     return view('tobuy')->with(['goods' => $goods, 'shops' => $shops]);

Comment: After the filter if "all" is selected - it should redirect to the original /toBuy route. If other value is selected it should go to the /filter route and filter out goods with the specific shop selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
if ($request->id == 'all'){
    $goods = Good::with('Shop')->get();
    $shops = Shop::all();
    return view('filter')->with(['goods' => $goods, 'shops' => $shops]);
} ...
```

Comment: nope, still the same. Im getting the id, but its probably something wrong with request. Like i said, works the first time, when i select another shop and resubmit - fails.

Comment: Okay I think I dont exactly understand your problem. What do you mean by " It seems that re-select is not working properly.". When is it not working?

Comment: @Benua Can you also explain why are you redirecting `->back()` in first part of `if`? This part actually doesn't make sense. First you make 2 model calls and then you don't do anything with the result. I've updated my answer, try this.

Comment: Look, i have a form at the top. Two tables(sql): Goods and Shops. Every good is assigned to a particular shop. When page loads i have all goods printed out in a list. When i select a shop inthe form and submit it - it filters out the goods which are assigned to that shop (first time it works). When i select another or the same shop and re-submit the form - it fails. No errors, just empty table..

Comment: Regarding the back part. As you see in the form there is a selection "all". So i check if "all" is selected i redirect back to the original page (where all goods are printed out). Another page is loaded only when a specific shop is selected. At least this is the idea of it :)

Comment: I would strongly recommend to create a separate route (url) for showing of 1 specific item only. Also this logic right now won't always work as you want it to. If you select 1 specific `id` and submit the filter you will get to the item you want (as expected). Then if you submit `all` you will just get redirected back to the page with 1 item only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144796/discussion-between-devk-and-benua).

Answer (score 0):

found mistake in blade file. In /toBuy route form name was 'id'. In filter file /filter form name was 'shop_id'. Functions were ok. Thank you for your efforts.